# Loop through divs inside div in Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="name">James</div>
    <div>Rodriguez</div>
    <div class="image">
        <div><img src="https://example.com/1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="name">Harry</div>
    <div>Kane</div>
    <div class="image">
        <div><img src="https://example.com/2.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I loop through all containers and get name, surname (second div) and image URL (img src)? So far I came up with this:

```
items = []

containers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="container"]')

for items in containers:
    name = items.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="name"]')
    print(name.text)
```

This should give two names. However, I'm getting 'James' twice as output, and no 'Harry'.

Thanks!

Comment: So what is your exact question here?

Comment: It's there: how do I loop through all containers and get name, surname (second div) and image URL (img src)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try below solution to get required values

```
for item in containers:
    name = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="name"]')
    surname = name.find_element_by_xpath('./following-sibling::div')
    image = surname.find_element_by_xpath('./following::img')
    print(name.text, surname.text, image.get_attribute('src'))
```

Answer (score 7):

When using `//` you are starting the search from the root node (`<html>`). Use `.` before the `xpath` to start the search from the element location

```
for items in containers:
    name = items.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="name"]')
    print(name.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, it indeed was the case. I chose Andersson's anwer as it was a bit more elaborate in terms of finding other items.